# Angular 6 form reset with values does not change the form dirty state

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a scenario wherein I make use of form's dirty state to enable/disable a button. When this form is reset with values, the dirty state of the form is not updated. I know I can update that using

```
this.form.markAsDirty();
```

but ideally I believe it should be updated when values are being reset? Any suggestions?

Comment: when you reset the form ,it means the form is in initial state as you would find for the first time. So its right that when you reset the form via code its not dirty i.e its pristine.

Comment: use an additional property to disable button like `[disabled]="disabled || other conditions"`

Comment: The form.dirty is getting reset. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1tru3